# why can not insert nest JSON data gps as a UNKNOWN type?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to insert a data into PostQSL data base from client to server. 
However, there is a error as:

Server error:

```
uid: test id
gps: 111
(node:8607) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: could not determine data type of parameter $2
```

why can I not insert nest JSON data gps as a UNKNOWN type?

client (Angular):

```
  tracking_info = {
       uid: "test id",
       gps: {
         logitude: 111,
         latitude: 222,
         timestamp: 12345,
       }
     }

  // Send data to server
  api.post('savemessage', tracking_info).share();
```

Server (Node.js)

```
    ...
    console.log("uid: "+ uid);
    console.log("gps: "+ gps.latitude);

    // insert a new message
    await client.query('INSERT INTO messages(uid, gps) VALUES($1, $2)', [uid, gps])
    ...
```

PostSQL Table Setting:

```
[Name]        [DataType]
 uid           VARCHAR
 gps           UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JSON data type for storing JSON data.

```
  CREATE TABLE tracking_info (  
    uid UUID NOT NULL,
    gps JSON
  );
```

You might need to do JSON.stringify.

```
await client.query('INSERT INTO messages(uid, gps) VALUES($1, $2)', [uid, JSON.stringify(gps)])
```

read for more details http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/